# Converting strings of form `<num>m<num>s` to `Maybe Double` Representing Total Minutes

Tags: haskell, time

In Haskell, is there some standard function to convert a string which might contain a minutes and seconds (i.e., something like this `34m30s`) to its appropriate `Maybe Double` of minutes? So in this case, we would convert `34m30s` to `Just 34.5`.

Comment: Do you have a good reason to be manipulating time as a `Double`? Why not leave it in a nice format? [`time`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/time-1.7) can parse a `TimeOfDay` from your format: `parseTimeM False defaultTimeLocale "%Mm%Ss" "34m30s"`.

Comment: If you need to convert it to a single numerical value, convert to an integer number of seconds, not a `Double` of minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answers based on `parseTimeM` seem to work only if the minutes and seconds are exactly two digits, so `parseMS "1m30s"` and `parseMS "12m0s"` both yield `Nothing`.

You really need a simple parser here.  Here's one that uses `reads` calls in a List monad.  Note that it will require both a minutes and seconds part with "m" and "s" suffixes, so "10m" and "10m30" and "15s" will all yield `Nothing`.  Also, it will accept negative numbers and leading spaces, so `"  10m -30s"` returns `Just 9.5`.

```
import Data.Maybe (listToMaybe)

readMS :: String -> Maybe Double
readMS str = listToMaybe $ do
  (mins, 'm':rest1) <- reads str
  (secs, "s")       <- reads rest1
  return (fromIntegral (mins :: Int) + fromIntegral (secs :: Int) / 60)
```

Some people find this easier to understand when it's written using the equivalent list comprehension, like so:

```
readMS1 :: String -> Maybe Double
readMS1 str = listToMaybe
  [ fromIntegral (mins :: Int) + fromIntegral (secs :: Int) / 60
  | (mins, 'm':rest1) <- reads str
  , (secs, "s")       <- reads rest1
  ]
```

A note of explanation, if you haven't seen this style before:  We're using the List monad, and each `reads` call returns a list of possible parses as `(value,rest_of_string)` pairs.  The first line of the do-block gets each possible parse of an integer `mins` followed by the letter "m" plus the `rest1` of the string.  The second line gets each possible parse of `rest1` as an integer `secs` followed by the letter "s" and nothing else.

If a match fails (e.g., no "s" at end of string), the monad/comprehension returns the empty list.  Otherwise, it returns a list of calculated Doubles from all possible parses (in this case, there will be at most one).  The `listToMaybe` function turns the empty list into `Nothing` and grabs the head of any other list to get a unique answer.

Comment: I guess I should have pointed out that you can add "guards" / conditions to the monad or comprehension to refuset, say, negative values or seconds  values >= 60.  For monads, you'd add:

Comment: Ugh..  hit Enter too early.  For the monad, you'd add `guard $ mins >=0` and `guard $ secs >=0 && secs <= 59` in the appropriate places.  In the list comprehension, you just write `mins >= 0` and `secs >= 0 && secs <= 59` clauses, without writing "guard".

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Data.Time.Format.parseTimeM`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/time-1.7/docs/Data-Time-Format.html#v:parseTimeM) to convert `String` to [`TimeOfDay`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/time-1.7/docs/Data-Time-LocalTime.html#t:TimeOfDay), then convert it to [`DiffTime`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/time-1.7/docs/Data-Time-Clock.html#t:DiffTime) and `Double`.

```
import Data.Time

parseMS :: String -> Maybe Double
parseMS = fmap (realToFrac . (/ 60) . timeOfDayToTime) . parseTimeM False defaultTimeLocale "%Mm%Ss"
```